# Jade Template if statement

Tags: node.js, if-statement, pug, each

I have a jade template file that I am trying to run a conditional based on a JSON object within an each loop. What am I doing wrong to get the if statement to work?

```
                each content in result.content
                  .panel.panel-default.result
                    .panel-heading.clearfix
                      a.gray(href='/content/#{content.id}') #{content.created_pretty}
                      a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm.view(href="/content/#{content.id}") View
                      .status
                        .well
                          span.label.label-default #{content.priority}
                        if "#{content.priority}" == "URGENT"
                          .well
                            span.badge !
```

If I change the conditional to

```
 if "URGENT" == "URGENT"
```

the code does run successfully.

I have also tried:

```
 if '"#{content.priority}" == "URGENT"'
 - if ("#{content.priority}" == "URGENT")
```

Any hlp would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do

```
if content.priority == "URGENT"
```

instead of

```
if "#{content.priority}" == "URGENT"
```